# <stropts.h> on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, posix, pintos

I'm trying to work [PintOS](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos_1.html) on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine, but I'm getting trouble with this library, did some research and apparently [stropts.h part of a POSIX XSR](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?194667-error-stropts-h-No-such-file-or-directory) option, which Linux now, says it is not supported.

My question is, I can somehow make this work on my Ubuntu 19.10? trying to figure this out before downgrading to 16.04 that works perfectly fine with PintOS.

Comment: Try `apt-get install libc6-dev`. If you already have it, you could also try simply deleting that include -- it only defines [STREAMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS) functions which were never implemented on Linux.